# kotlin var is working like it is immutable

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to figure out the differences of mutable and immutability in kotlin.

```
    var a = "abcd"
    println(System.identityHashCode(a)) //495053715
    var b = a
    a = "1234"
    println(System.identityHashCode(a)) //1922154895
    println(System.identityHashCode(b)) // 495053715
```

initially, `a` has some value. So, an object is created in string pool and its reference is given to variable `a`
the object's hashcode is `495053715`

Then, `b` is assigned the value `a`
So, its hashcode is same as above. which is wrong i'll explain it later

Now, when `a` value is changed it is acting like immutable.

> Why it created one more object with hashcode `1922154895` to load value "1234" ?

According to me,

- it should overwrite the value in object `495053715` whose previous value is "abcd"
- Then for `b` a new object should be created

If it satisfy above points then I can accept it as `Mutable`. 
So Kindly clarify me with examples.

Comment: Reassigning a variable does not overwrite the value in old object, it creates a new object and assigns the value to the variable. `a` and `b` are reference to two different objects.

Comment: When you do `var b = a`, you are simply making `b` reference the same object as `a`. When you do `a = "1234"`, then you change the object which `a` is referencing, while `b` remains the same. The `a` has been mutated (and is therefore mutable), but the string `"abcd"` is still the same and is immutable.

Comment: @Ashwani kotlin says var is mutable. I'm going by definition

Comment: var is mutable because you can reassign it, like you do with `a = "1234"`. If it were immutable (a `val`), that line wouldn't compile.

Comment: @naanu No, it does not. Even when you mutate an object, you are just reassigning some mutable variable inside it.

Comment: @marstran mutable means, in same object the value will be overwritten. In java perspective. And you are talking about reassigning. Remember, String is immutable and can be reassigned in java.

Comment: Yes, the `String` class is immutable, and a string variable can be mutable `String s = "abcd"` (no `final` modifier). To be able to reassign the value of a variable, it must be mutable.

Comment: @marstran try with array as it is mutable. you will see if you change a value in a array then b array's value will also get changed.

Comment: @naanu Changing a value in array is different from reassigning the variable. Try reassigning the variable to new array.

Comment: @marstran is it possible to print object hashcode of variable. what hascode I'm printing now ?

Comment: @marstran i understood what you said. But, how to look it by example in real.

Comment: You are confused between mutating the reference and mutating the underlying object.
`val` just makes the reference immutable not the underlying object just like `final` keyword in java.

Comment: You explicitly assign the a to a new String object, you didn't changed the original String object, so hasCode has changed since they are different references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're conflating two different meanings for the word *mutable*.

When we say a **variable** or **property** is mutable (with the `var` keyword), that means we can reassign it to point at a different object.

When we say an **object** is mutable, that means it *contains* publicly mutable properties.

Marking a property or variable mutable with `var` allows it to be reassigned to point to different objects. It has no effect on whether those pointed-at objects are mutable or not. It cannot bestow mutable properties upon any objects it happens to point to.

`String` is always immutable. A `String` `var` is one that can be reassigned to point at different immutable `String`s.

You mentioned familiarity with Java in the comments. `var` is exactly like any variable in Java that you have not marked as `final`.